# How to retrieve environment variables from remote branch with git pull

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I'm using intellij. I recently pulled from my colleague's remote branch. But I found the environment variables are still the ones I added. Is there anyway to pull the environment variables from remote branch along with code?

The operations I made were click the branches at lower right corner. Then I clicked my colleague's remote branch, then click pull into 'my local branch' Using Merge.

Comment: What environment variables are you talking about?

Comment: The things that Java and Git call "environment variables" are not stored *in* Git. As such they literally can't be updated via `git pull`.

Answer (score 1):

IDE may not have an access to these env. variables, since IDE inherits environment variables from a parent process (JetBrains Toolbox, cmd etc) and there is no action in IDE to reload enviroment variables, once they come from another branch.

There is a feature request for this:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-237257